# Is there any truth to this story about Coolidge?

Tags: united-states, president

I read years ago the following story: A couple were driving through Vermont and saw, on a day that threatened rain, a farmer moving hay into a barn. It was apparently normal in those days to help strangers and they stopped and helped him. The man asked them where they were headed and they said they were taking a vacation to Washington DC. The farmer suggested that they go to his son's house for dinner and they ended up at the White House.

Googling is not yielding this story -- I wonder if anyone knows if this is a true story and where it can be found.

Comment: **[Calvin Coolidge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calvin_Coolidge)** served as President 1923 to 1929.   His father **[John Calvin Coolidge Sr](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Calvin_Coolidge_Sr.)** was a farmer / politician / judge in Vermont, who passed away March 18, 1926.  So maybe.. but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @JMS: sure, it is possible because of his dad having been a farmer and in fact i did read this story -- unless it was made up by the person who wrote the book, it did happen. i would just like to find a link to it.

Comment: Its certainly a boring enough story to be about Coolidge. My personal favorite Coolidge story is the one about a reporter who scored an interview, but was disappointed to discover that he got nothing but refusals to answer and "no comments" for all his questions. On his way out the door Coolidge called him back, and the reporter hoped he'd finally get some information to print, only to be told, "Now remember, don't quote me."

Comment: Of course the story itself isn't really possible, as its a 10 hour drive from Vermont to the White House even today, but it certainly sounds enough in character that it could have been an extant Coolidge joke back when he was relevant.

Comment: of course it is possible. not dinner that same day but after they got to DC which would have taken probably a few days at least.

Comment: @T.E.D. possible to displace your current favorite with this one? https://www.historyextra.com/period/the-coolidge-effect/